# relative interior $\operatorname{relint}(C)$ of convex $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ set is again convex

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, convex-optimization

I'm trying to show that the relative interior $\operatorname{relint}(C)$ of a convex set $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ is again convex.

Using the following definition of the rel. interior

$\operatorname{relint}(X) := \{x \in X\mid  \exists \epsilon > 0: \mathbb{B}(\epsilon, x) \cap \operatorname{aff}(X) \subset X\}$

I've got the steps:

let $x,y \in \operatorname{relint}(C)$, each with $\epsilon_x, \epsilon_y$. Then there must be $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \in \operatorname{relint}(C)$, i.e. their convex comb. must be in the interior as well, to show the above.

then the convex combination of $x,y$ is clearly in $\operatorname{aff}(C)$ but I don't know how to proceed with the ball.

I would have to show that there's a ball $\mathbb{B}(\epsilon', \lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)$ and that its intersection with the affine hull is in C again. Am I right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon =\min(\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2)$, and let $\|r\|<\varepsilon$ with $x+r\in {\rm Aff}(C)$, then $y+r=(x+r)+y-x\in {\rm Aff}(C)$ as well, and 
$$\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y+r\ =\ \lambda(x+r)+(1-\lambda)(y+r)\ \in C$$
because both $x+r$ and $y+r$ are in $C$ by hypothesis, and $C$ is convex.

Comment: thanks! so we pick r s.t. it is included in a ball and therefore is in the intersection as well, right? And because it was in the smaller of the two balls, also the combination with the other point has to be in the affine hull. but I don't get the connection to the rel. interior. could you please elaborate?

Comment: Let $s:= \lambda x+(1-\lambda)y$. If $z\in {\rm Aff}(C)\cap \Bbb B(\varepsilon,s)$, then apply it for $r=z-s$.

Comment: (Note that ${\rm Aff}(C)-x= {\rm Aff}(C)-s={\rm Aff}(C)-y$ is a linear subspace.)