# How to prove $\mathrm{aff}(\mathrm{relint}(C))=\mathrm{aff}(C)$ for convex sets $C \subset \mathbb R^n$?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $C$ be any convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $\mathrm{cl}(C)$ and $\mathrm{relint}(C)$ have the same affine hull. I know $\mathrm{aff}(\mathrm{cl}(C))=\mathrm{aff}(C)$. But how to prove that
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{aff}(\mathrm{relint}(C))=\mathrm{aff}(C) \ ?
\end{equation}

Comment: Can you mention what relint is? [This here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3675971/relative-interior-operatornamerelintc-of-convex-c-subset-mathbbrn)?

Comment: Yes,  relative interiors  of C

Comment: By definition, $\mathrm{relint}(C)$ is open in $\mathrm{aff}(C)$. The affine hull of any open set in an affine space is the affine space itself.

Comment: I can imagine what you mean roughly, but I can't prove it exactly. In other words, I'm looking at Theorem 2.1.3 in Fundamental of Convex Analysis (by Jean -Baptiste), which transforms the problem to simply prove the following:                             $\text{aff}(A)=\text{aff}(B)$,  A is convex hull defines by $A = \text{conv}\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_k\}$, $B=\{\sum_{i=0}^{k}a_i x_i: \sum_{i=0}^k a_i = 1, a_i>0  \text{for } i = 0,1 ,\dots,k\}$

Comment: Check Rockafellar's *Convex Analysis* which continues to be the ultimate reference for the relative interior.

Comment: @max_zorn  Thank you, but actually, I didn't understand the proof of the theorem corresponding to Rockafellar's Convex Analysis. So I try to  search other books for a proof of this theorem...

Comment: @YilinCheng I think you are best of to explain where exactly you got stuck in his proof. Only people with huge amounts of time will type up the entire proof!

Comment: @max_zorn  OK, What confuses me is the following: let $A=\operatorname{conv}\left\{x_{0}, x_{1}, \ldots, x_{k}\right\}$, $B=\left\{\sum_{i=0}^{k} a_{i} x_{i}: \sum_{i=0}^{k} a_{i}=1, a_{i}>0\right.$ for $\left.i=0,1, \ldots, k\right\}$. How to prove that  $aff(A)=aff(B)$ ?

Comment: @YilinCheng $B$ is a dense subset of $A$. And both affine hulls are closed, so they must coincide.

Comment: @max_zorn Thank you very much. My ability is relatively poor, and I may not be able to understand your thoughts accurately for a while. But I just suddenly understood the proof process from the definition point of view (a certain two relative interior point affine combination can represent $x_0,x_1,\dots,x_k$). So in any case, I thank you very much. 
And my question is  solved.

Comment: @YilinCheng Excellent! It is always helpful to explain problems to other people! Cheers.

Comment: @YilinCheng Why not write your own answer here for the community :)?

Comment: @user550103 OK, i will write my answer.  (～￣▽￣)～

Answer (score 0):

Easy to prove  $\mathrm{aff}(A)\subset\mathrm{aff}\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_k\}$

Now, if $\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_k\}\subset \mathrm{aff}(B)$, then we can obtain
$\mathrm{aff}\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_k\}\subset \mathrm{aff}(B)$, therefore, $\mathrm{aff}(A)\subset\mathrm{aff}(B)$.

To prove $\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_k\}\subset \mathrm{aff}(B)$. For example, $x_0=2*\alpha+(-1)*\beta$

$\alpha=\frac{k+2}{2k+2}x_0+\frac{1}{2k+2}x_1+\cdots+\frac{1}{2k+2}x_k$ and $\beta=\frac{1}{k+1}x_0+\frac{1}{k+1}x_1+\cdots+\frac{1}{k+1}x_k$. we know that $\alpha,\beta \in B$. So, the proof is complete.